# Component constantly re-rendering when dispatching action (promise)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

When I run the code with `this.props.addChannel(payload);`
Channel Component keeps re-rendering like its in an infinity loop.

When I replace it with `console.log(payload)` it works fine.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.shared.user,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addChannel: (payload) => dispatch({type:ADD_CHANNEL, payload})
});


class Channel extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        const payload = api.Channels.getAll();
        this.props.addChannel(payload);
        //console.log("Channels", payload)

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <AddChannel />
            <ChannelList channels={[{text:"test"}]} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Channel);
```

The api code:

```
const Channels = {
  getAll: () => requests.get('channels/twitter/')
};
```

The Reducer:

```
import {ADD_CHANNEL} from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export default (state={}, action={}) => {
   switch(action.type){
      case ADD_CHANNEL:
         return {...state};
      default:
         return {...state};
   }
};
```

The Routes Component:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Auth from './containers/Auth';
import Channel from './containers/Channel';
import Messages from './containers/Messages';
import withAuth from './components/Auth/WithAuth';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.shared.user,
});


class Routes extends Component{
  render(){
     const user = this.props.user;

     return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Auth} />
            <Route path='/messages' component={withAuth(Messages, user)} />
            <Route exact path='/channels' component={withAuth(Channel, user)} />
        </Switch>
    );
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, ()=>({}),null,{pure:false})(Routes);
```

Comment: What does `api.Channels.getAll()` do?

Comment: Calls a django rest api and returns a promise.  Authentication promise works fine except the channels one                                  
`const Auth = {
    login: (data) => requests.post(LoginUrl, data)
};`

Comment: You're not controlling this async action. your `payload` variable is probably `undefined` when it gets passed to `this.props.addChannel`

Comment: Am using `redux-promise`. Returns a value when promise is resolved else it doesnt. Also when console logging the payload it works fine.

Comment: Oh, ok. Can you post your reducer as well?

Comment: Why is your `ADD_CHANNEL` `action.type` not incorporating `action.payload` into your new state? edit: Oh, for some reason I didn't read your second statement. So it doesn't work when you have `const location = action.payload` and then `return {...state, location}` ?

Comment: action.type not incorporating action.payload into your new state Meaning?  For now am just returning the previous state.

Comment: Can you post the parent component of `Channel`?

Comment: Can you try changing `addChannel: (payload) => dispatch({type:ADD_CHANNEL, payload})` to `addChannel: (payload) => { dispatch({type:ADD_CHANNEL, payload})}`

Comment: I'm sorry about assaulting you with questions, but I can't believe I forgot to ask: Do you have any life cycle events that have some sort of listener to your `this.prop.location` in your redux `store`? `ComponentWillReceiveProps`, `shouldComponentUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate`, etc. etc. This can be in any component that uses `this.props.location`

Comment: @bennygenel tried that still in the infinity loop.

Comment: @andrew The only lifecycle used is componentDidMount in Channel and Auth components

Comment: @palsreallm Posted

Comment: @NickMaina I am talking about any component that is connected to redux that has `location` in its props that have an update listener in it. It doesn't need a child/parent relationship for a redux dispatch to affect another component.

Comment: @andrew yes the withAuth High Order Component passes `{match: {…}, location: {…}, history: {…}, staticContext: undefined}` as props

Comment: @NickMaina are there lifecycle events in it that are constantly called while the component is mounted? Anything that is not `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount`, and `componentWillUnmount` are constantly called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156692/discussion-between-nick-maina-and-andrew).

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the loop is probably the call to your higher-order component `withAuth` in the `component` prop of your `Route`'s. (see [`Route component` docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component))

This call will return a new component each time `Routes` is rendered, which will mount a fresh `Channel` with an accompanying api call and redux store update. Because of `{pure: false}`, the store update will then trigger a rerendering of `Routes` (even though `user` hasn't changed) and start a new cycle of the loop.

If you drop `{pure: false}` (which doesn't seem useful here) you'll probably end the loop, but the `Channel` component will still do unnecessary re-mounting if one of its ancestors rerenders, resetting all local component state in `Channel` and below.

To fix this, you could refactor `withAuth` to get `user` as a prop rather than a parameter, and call it on the top level, outside the `Routes` class:

```
const AuthMessages = withAuth(Messages);
const AuthChannel = withAuth(Channel);
```

Now you can pass `user` to these components by using the `render` prop of `Route`:

```
<Route path='/messages' render={(props) => <AuthMessages {...props} user={user}/>}/> 
<Route exact path='/channels' render={(props) => <AuthChannel {...props} user={user}/>}/>
```

Besides this, you will probably want to keep the channels in the store and handle the api call asynchronously, but I assume this code is more of a work in progress.